# change default scala platform netbeans?

Tags: scala, netbeans

I want to change my default Scala platform in netbeans under

```
tools->scala platforms
```

I cannot delete the default platform and I can't define another default platform, just additional ones!

The default platform path doesnt work (error) and somehow it does not find  scala  when i copy the scala platform to the path of the default platform.

Is there a way to do this in NetBeans or in the NetBeans config files?

thanks for any help!

**Answer(Max OSX):**

Go to

```
/installation/path/NetBeans x.y.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
```

change netbeans_defaut_options:

```
netbeans_default_options="..... -J-Dscala.home=/scala/installation/path/scala-x.x.x.y"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if the notion of scala platform is still relevant with the current versions of the [Scala Netbeans plugin](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala).
See [bug 172214](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=172214):

> Per nightly built version of Scala plugin, I have removed bundled Scala runtime (the latest was still in 2.7.3), and may not add it back.
>   The reason is that Scala 2.8.0 changes a lot and is not in beta yet, `scala.editor` module should sync with Scala 2.8's development progress frequently.
>
> I'll try to get `scala.stdplatform` module working with the scala sdk under environment $SCALA_HOME.

The latest [NetBeans6.9 Scala instructions](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala69) recommend setting `$SCALA_HOME` environment variable to point to the installed Scala runtime path.
And to Add `$SCALA_HOME/bin` to `PATH` environment variable.